# post publish updated version of application in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I want to launch updated version of my application in android market. Is it possible that I will launch updated version in android market but it is not visible to user for some time(for eg. 7 days) and it is visible to user when I want. I want to do this because I have same application in apple store and windows store. for apple and windows to launch updated version it takes 3-4 days. My application is server based. So I want to launch all updated version on same day and on same time.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK Its not possible for same time..... but can be possible for same day (BUT possibilities are again less)... in current Google takes 1 day (as I realize while updating  my 3 apps) to show updated version of your application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that for Android app.

I would suggest you that for ios app you should set the availability of your app after approval to your discretion. As soon as you receive the mail from apple that your app is approved you can upload the Android app on Google Play.

Now it takes a few hours for your app to show updated version in Google play, so you can make your ios app available in 2-3 hours after android app update.

BTW all users are not going to update the app at the same time so there are going to be some differences in versions between their apps.